# Is it possible to connect to azure analysis service using langchain?

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, langchain

I'm doing a lab working with langchain and different databases, the documentation is clear and I don't have any problem connecting and making queries using openAi, but I'm testing if I can connect to azure analysis service to make queries.

```
from langchain import OpenAI, SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("mssql+pymssql://est.asazure.windows.net/test")
```

He tries to connect but generates a timeout, so I have several doubts:
Is it possible to make that connection?
How do I define the authentication, which in this case is through AD?